# How can I convert double to string in Java ME

Tags: java, string, java-me, double

How can I convert a `double` into a `String` in Java for Mobile phones?

Note that this does not work:

```
double lat = 22.456464;
String strLat = String.valueOf(lat);
```

Neither does this:

```
String str = Double.toString(double).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting double to string Java ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069384/converting-double-to-string-java-me)

Comment: Already you asked right? why you don't update your previous question? same problem you asked two topics.

Comment: Yes I asked it twice because the other answers were wrong. Thanks for dropping my exp! I suggest you negate their points for not reading my first question properly!!!!

Comment: Ok this ones better, I'll delete the old topic.

Comment: Please don't ask questions twice just because you don't like the answers. I agree that the people posting the original answers didn't read the question, but that's what the voting system is for, and we also have flags for "not an answer" which can be applied, and thus those answers deleted. Also, for future reference, if you have tried N things and none of those work, and N is fairly low, please post those things in the question itself.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll get the hang of it. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you try

```
double lat = 22.456464;
String strLat = "" + lat;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is typo in your code:

```
String str = Double.toString(double).
```

It should work this way:

```
String str = Double.toString(lat);
```

`Double` class CLDC 1.1 contains the method:

```
 public static String toString(double d)
```

Older or more limited API may not have the method or `Double` class.